# How can I start the plasma login screen from a terminal?

Tags: login, plasma, ubuntu-studio

It often happens, that the login screen disappears, before I can log in.
I have the possibility, to start a terminal session by Alt-Ctrl-F2.

From there I can reboot or I could start something, but I don't know, how to start the login screen again, to get all my settings loaded.

What is the command?

Sorry, I've forgotten:

```
$ cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager
/usr/bin/sddm


Operating System: Ubuntu Studio 22.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.7
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3
Kernel Version: 5.19.0-1023-lowlatency (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 16 × 13th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-13700K
Memory: 62.6 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: llvmpipe
```

Comment: Using "startx" loads the Plasma desktop, but all the settings are not applied ...

Comment: Please add `cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager` to your question.

Comment: `sudo systemctl stop sddm.service && sudo systemctl start sddm.service`

Answer (score 2):

This will restart the desktop manager:

```
sudo systemctl restart sddm.service
```

Thanks to @nobody